# MySQL Trigger on update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a database with 2 tables. One tables contains data regarding references (job refs) the other contains votes. In order to get to the vote stage, you need 5 references. In another database, i must change a group_id once they have 5 refs.

I was trying to use something like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_group AFTER UPDATE ON refs
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF (SELECT recruit_id from refs where count(refs) = 5) THEN
        UPDATE users.members
        SET group_id=10
        WHERE member_id=recruit_id;
    END;
```

Is something like this even feasible? if this doesn't work, my fallback is to use a bash script in a cron job that runs every 5 minutes, but a trigger just seems so much more efficient (and instantaneous)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `NEW.` to refer respectively affected `recruit_id` after change, do a count and update the foreign table accordingly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_group AFTER UPDATE ON refs
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      SELECT @refs_no := count(*) from refs where recruit_id = NEW.recruit_id 
      IF (@refs_no = 5) THEN
        UPDATE users.members
        SET group_id=10
        WHERE member_id=NEW.recruit_id;
    END;
```

Comment: thanks for replying! im getting this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@refs_no Integer;
      SELECT @refs_no := count(refs) from refs where recruit_i' at line 4
`